# Handling a smart Combobox in a userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I found this smart code that lists the hits while you type the name in, like a quick search. Everything works fine, but if i click on the arrow next to the combobox and select something from the list, I have to press enter before it triggers. I want it to run my "viewProject" when clicked. Secondly and a bonus is that if the list on the active sheet contains less than 3 objects, the code gets error. I did a quick fix, making a space if that would accure. Is there a better way?
Thanks for your help!

```
Option Explicit

Private Comb_Arrow As Boolean

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim i As Long
If ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2) = "" Then ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2) = " "
If ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2) = "" Then ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2) = " "
If Not Comb_Arrow Then
    With ComboBox1
        .List = ActiveSheet.Range("B2", Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp)).value
        .ListRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(4, .ListCount)
        .DropDown
        If Len(.text) Then
            For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
                If InStr(1, .List(i), .text, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then .RemoveItem i
            Next
            .DropDown
        End If
    End With
End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
Comb_Arrow = (KeyCode = vbKeyUp) Or (KeyCode = vbKeyDown)
If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
    With ComboBox1
        If .ListIndex = -1 And .LineCount > 0 Then
            .ListIndex = 0
        End If
        .List = ActiveSheet.Range("B2", Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp)).value
        If .ListIndex > -1 Then
            Call viewProject
        End If
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have found the solution yourself by now but for future readers (and possible you still), here goes:

The issue with your `.List` throwing an error was not 3 but 2 rows (since you start looking from B2) and if you have B3 empty, only one value is given to .List while it expects an array. Range("B2").Value = just the value while Range("B2:B3").Value is an array.

As for the click, you can normally just use the Click event for that:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    If rng.Count < 2 Then Set rng = rng.Resize(2) 'get the empty cell beneath it as well
    If Not Comb_Arrow Then
        With ComboBox1
            .List = rng.Value
            .ListRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(4, .ListCount)
            .DropDown
            If Len(.Text) Then
                For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
                    If InStr(1, .List(i), .Text, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then .RemoveItem i
                Next
                .DropDown
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    viewProject 'this should only run your macro when selecting a list item
End Sub
```